# Bootstrap modal title not visible

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

The title in the modal isn't visible.

If I highlight it with a mouse it will become visible. I tried adding `modal-content` `color: #000`, but without results.

The responses and answers as of *01/11/16 1:28PM CST* did not correct the situation.

I should have mentioned I'm trying to get ahead of the game; using Bootstrap 4 Alpha. Don't see any changes in the modal section of 4 that would have any effect though and setting `top: 100px` worked. Any other suggestion will certainly be appreciated.

Any ideas on what is wrong within the **HTML** code?

```html
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
        Newsletter
    </button>
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" 
         aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <!-- Modal Header -->
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" 
                       data-dismiss="modal">
                           <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                           <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
                    </button>
                    <h4 class="text-body modal-title" id="myModalLabel">
                        Subscribe to Newsletter
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
          <form class="form-signin">
            <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Receive Our Newsletter</h2>
            <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Name</label>
            <input type="email" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" required autofocus>
            <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">City &amp; State</label>
             <input type="email" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="City &amp; State" required autofocus>
            <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Email address</label>
            <input type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address" required>
        <hr>
            <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-sm" type="submit">Subscribe</button>
          </form>        
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: looks like the titles are showing: https://jsfiddle.net/k1kvy0es/2/

Comment: @BinaryGhost It may have to do with his stylesheet, he may have a theme.

Comment: Works for me too, where's your CSS?

Comment: @user5593012 Why are you putting the color on the "content" of the modal, if its the title that is having issues? You should put the text color on modal-title.

Comment: I am having the same problem with bootstrap 3. The title does not show, but I can highlight it. When I inspect element and toggle the color, it appears properly. Sometimes, if I refresh and try again, it will show. I used the demo straight from the bootstrap3 website and customized the colors with basic CSS. 

Have you found a solution to this problem yet?

Answer (score 1):

```
.modal-title {
    color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same situation and realized that I was using wrong version of bootstrap css.

I had to take off the `fade` css class.

In your case, this is what you have

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" 
 aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
```

It should be

```
<div class="modal" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" 
 aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            <strong>
            <h2 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel" >
                Subscribe to Newsletter
            </h2></strong>
```

Answer (score 0):

In perspective - your code with a bit of formatting, the bootstrap 4.2 code
put this in an html file - it works

it works, has to be your stylesheet ...

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
            Newsletter

        </button>

        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <!-- Modal Header -->
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                            <span class="sr-only">Close</span>

                        </button>

                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">
                            Subscribe to Newsletter
                        </h4>

                    </div>


                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <form class="form-signin">
                            <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Receive Our Newsletter</h2>
                            <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Name</label>
                            <input type="email" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" required autofocus>
                            <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">City &amp; State</label>
                            <input type="email" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="City &amp; State" required autofocus>
                            <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Email address</label>
                            <input type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address" required>
                            <hr>
                            <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-sm" type="submit">Subscribe</button>
                        </form>

                    </div>

                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **class="text-body"** in the header tag where you have written the modal title

Comment: Why? What effect does that have? How does that solve the problem?